# Which data type is the result of division？

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

List the round function in postgres:

```
\df  round
                         List of functions
   Schema   | Name  | Result data type | Argument data types | Type 
------------+-------+------------------+---------------------+------
 pg_catalog | round | double precision | double precision    | func
 pg_catalog | round | numeric          | numeric             | func
 pg_catalog | round | numeric          | numeric, integer    | func
```

The argument for round must be double precision,numeric,integer.

```
select  6::float/3.3 as number;
       number       
--------------------
 1.8181818181818183
(1 row)
```

If its data type is double precision :

```
select  round(6::float/3.3,4) as number;
ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: select  round(6::float/3.3,4) as number;
                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Time: 0.517 ms
```

Which data type is the  result of division----`1.8181818181818183`？

Comment: You can always check things like that with [`pg_typeof()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#id-1.5.8.32.6.3.2.2.29.1.1.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always check things like that with [`pg_typeof()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#id-1.5.8.32.6.3.2.2.29.1.1.1): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/YZLaXcw4)

```
select pg_typeof(6::float/3.3) as number_type;
```

| number_type |
| --- |
| double precision |

The reason your function call didn't work is that `\df` showed you *three different* [`round()` functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#id-1.5.8.9.6.2.2.23.1.1.1). The first two accept exactly **one** argument:

> `round ( numeric ) → numeric`
>
> `round ( double precision ) → double precision`
>
> Rounds to nearest integer. For `numeric`, ties are broken by rounding away from zero. For `double precision`, the tie-breaking behavior is platform dependent, but “round to nearest even” is the most common rule.

and only the one accepting `numeric` has a variant with a 2nd argument, `integer`, to specify how
many decimal places you want to round to.

> `round ( v numeric,` **`s integer`** `) → numeric`
>
> Rounds `v` to `s` decimal places. Ties are broken by rounding away from zero.

So if you cast to `::numeric` instead or don't cast at all and let PostgreSQL [presume `numeric` by default](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-NUMERIC), you can get that one to get picked:

```
select round(6/3.3,4) as number;
```

| number |
| --- |
| 1.8182 |

---

[Here's the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH) on result types in mixed-type mathematical operations:

> Calls involving multiple argument data types, such as `integer` + `numeric`, are resolved by using the type appearing later in these lists.

The list in question being "*`smallint`, `integer`, `bigint`, `numeric`, `real`, and `double precision`*". Here's a cheatsheet:

| divident | /smallint divisor | /integer divisor | /bigint divisor | /numeric divisor | /real divisor | /double precision divisor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| smallint | smallint | integer | bigint | numeric | double precision | double precision |
| integer | integer | integer | bigint | numeric | double precision | double precision |
| bigint | bigint | bigint | bigint | numeric | double precision | double precision |
| numeric | numeric | numeric | numeric | numeric | double precision | double precision |
| real | double precision | double precision | double precision | double precision | real | double precision |
| double precision | double precision | double precision | double precision | double precision | double precision | double precision |

Comment: If argument data type is double precission,round function contain only one argument!