# How to calculate the fraction of rows fulfilling some criteria in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I would like to calculate the fraction of rows fulfilling some criteria. So something like this:

```sql
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM table 
 WHERE col_name > crit
 ) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table);
```

However, this creates a syntax error when I tried it.

How can I realize what I want?

Comment: You asked the same question on dba.SE a few minutes prior: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/337344/3684. Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Especially not without declaring as much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *are* using perfectly valid syntax. It's just incomplete, missing a `select` out front: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/mPPo1454)

```sql
SELECT (
  SELECT COUNT(*)::float
  FROM tbl
  WHERE col_name > .5
  ) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl);
```

That makes your two parenthesized expressions uncorrelated [scalar subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) of the outer `select`. Note that you [need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77885791/5298879) the divident or the divisor to be `numeric`, `real` or `float` to get a fraction, otherwise the result of dividing integers from `count(*)` will be rounded.

The proper (also quickest) way to do that is using [aggregate `filter` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE col_name > .5)
  / COUNT(*)::float
FROM tbl;
```

Picking `float`/`double precision` over `numeric`, you won't have to round off trailing zeroes.

Comment: To clarify and avoid people projecting their [fear of floating point number arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems): the cast to `float` here is offered as an *output* trick to round off **only** trailing `0`'s for viewing: not for manipulating precision, not as a "favourite" numeric type. I figured it's reasonable to assume the precision actually required here is low, so the entire point of `decimal`/`numeric` being exact and more precise when needed, is of no use. Especially if you plan to truncate/round all those hard-earned digits off.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax would be:

```
select (select count(*)::decimal from table where col_name > crit) / count(*)::decimal
from table
```

But you can (mis)use the `avg` function too:

```
select avg(case when col_name > crit then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
from table
```