# How to query a Postgresql DB for a fraction of rows fulfilling a criterion in a sliding time window?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

This is a follow-up on my previous post
[How calculate the fraction of rows fulfilling a criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78079765/how-to-calculate-the-fraction-of-rows-fulfilling-some-criteria-in-postgresql)

I have a time-stamped table of a kind:

```
timestamp: timestamp
field1: double
...
more fields
```

What I would like to achieve is a time stamped, rolling fraction of rows fulfilling a criterion in a certain time window. For example, the fraction of rows fulfilling "field1 > crit" in the last minute/5 hours/day.

I already found a way to calculate the average of field1 over a sliding window of rows:

```
SELECT timestamp, avg(a.field1)
   OVER(ORDER BY a.timestamp ROWS BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
   AS output_name
   FROM schema."table" a;
```

But I do not manage to extend this to what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`range` window frame clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KzKzt-34)

```sql
SELECT timestamp, 
       a.field1,
       count(*)filter(where a.field1>5)over w1
        / (count(*)over w1)::float AS "fraction of field1 > crit",
       avg(a.field1)over w1,
       min(a.field1)over w1,
       max(a.field1)over w1
FROM schema1."table1" AS a
WINDOW w1 AS (ORDER BY a.timestamp 
              RANGE BETWEEN '1 hour' PRECEDING 
                        AND CURRENT ROW)
LIMIT 10;
```

| timestamp | field1 | fraction of field1 > crit | avg | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-29 02:52:29.352841 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 2024-02-29 03:06:52.759728 | 2 | 0.5 | 4 | 2 | 6 |
| 2024-02-29 03:10:21.047632 | 9 | 0.6666666666666666 | 5.666666666666667 | 2 | 9 |
| 2024-02-29 03:37:06.321381 | 0 | 0.5 | 4.25 | 0 | 9 |
| 2024-02-29 03:45:06.147972 | 10 | 0.6 | 5.4 | 0 | 10 |
| 2024-02-29 03:48:36.642597 | 3 | 0.5 | 5 | 0 | 10 |
| 2024-02-29 04:17:40.280552 | 8 | 0.5 | 5.25 | 0 | 10 |
| 2024-02-29 04:19:19.055374 | 10 | 0.6 | 6.2 | 0 | 10 |
| 2024-02-29 04:27:43.887064 | 1 | 0.5 | 5.333333333333333 | 0 | 10 |
| 2024-02-29 04:54:47.489977 | 9 | 0.75 | 7 | 1 | 10 |